# Issues connecting my Node.js backend to my AWS RDS MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

how are you?

I'm having issues connecting my Node.js backend to my AWS RDS MySQL database. I migrated from Digital Ocean to AWS, which was working perfectly within Digital Ocean. However, after migrating to AWS and executing npm run start locally, I receive the following error:

> getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND databaseX.xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com
> parent: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND  databaseX.xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26) {
> errno: -3007,
> code: 'ENOTFOUND',
> syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
> hostname: 'databaseX.xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com',
> fatal: true
> },

Additionally, within the EC2 instance or using Insomnia locally, I can execute the npm run start command or even connect to the database perfectly. But locally, I can't connect using the same command:

mysql -h databaseX.xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -p

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, I've opened all connections in the security group but still can't connect in any way. I will share my security groups and my code for connecting to the database.

this is how I am connecting to the databse using node.js

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import fs from 'fs';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME!, process.env.DB_USER!, process.env.DB_PASSWORD!, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST!,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            require: true,
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            ca: fs.readFileSync('./certificates/ca-certificate-aws.pem').toString(),
        },
    },
});

export default sequelize;


DB_NAME=databaseX
DB_USER=admin
DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
DB_HOST=databaseX.xxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-3.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
```

this is how I configure the security groups, do I need to open more gates?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is public access enabled in the RDS instance? If not, you can't directly connect to the instance from the local machine. You can connect to it via port forwarding to RDS

Comment: here you go! It was that mistake, XD. thanks toma